# ExactTarget v5 Salesforce Integration - Send Automated Emails to Salesforce Report

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, massemailmessage, automation

I'm wondering if anyone has found a way to send automated emails using the v5 integration of ExactTarget with Salesforce. Some documentation from the v2 integration seems to say that this is possible ([see here](https://3sixty.exacttarget.com/Portals/0/Content/Documents/ExactTarget_for_Appexchange_AIM_Scenario.pdf)), but I haven't been able to set up an automated email program that sends to a Salesforce report.

We want to set up a program that sends an automated email everyday to 3 separate Salesforce reports that contain contacts who 1) Signed up for the newsletter via webform YESTERDAY 2) Signed up for the newsletter via webform 14 DAYS AGO and 3) Signed up for the newsletter via webform 28 DAYS AGO. We have the reports all set up, but can't seem to automate the process with ExactTarget like we thought we could.

The link above says to set up a User-Initiated Email and add it to a newly created Program to automate it. However, I can't make a Salesforce report the recipient of a User-Initiated Email. I can make a Salesforce report the recipient of a Salesforce Sends Email, but I can't add a Salesforce Sends Email to a Program. I also can't send a Simple Automated Email to a Salesforce report.

Has anyone found a way to send an ExactTarget automated email to a Salesforce report, either from ExactTarget, or from the Salesforce integration?

Comment: Have you had success with the guided send to a SF report, found here?

http://help.exacttarget.com/documentation/integrated_products__crm_and_web_analytic_solutions/exacttarget_salesforce_integration_v5/v5_user_guide/sending/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Great news people we can now send automated emails with ExactTarget/Salesforce v5. You need to ask ExactTarget to provide your users access to Salesforce Automation Studio Activity. Once done you go to the following link to do your automation:

https://help.exacttarget.com/en/documentation/integrated_products__crm_and_web_analytic_solutions/exacttarget_salesforce_integration_v5/creating_a_salesforce_send_definition/

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I am also waiting for this to be implemented for Salesforce v5. ExactTarget is saying its possible see link below:

https://help.exacttarget.com/en/documentation/integrated_products__crm_and_web_analytic_solutions/exacttarget_salesforce_integration_v5/automation_studio_support/

I have tried it out but l cannot select Salesforce sends.

Comment: I spoke with ExactTarget recently and they said that the Send Salesforce Email Activity isn't currently available in the Automation Studio unless you have the Journey Builder feature that goes with the Automation Studio. They did say that they plan on enabling the Salesforce send activity for existing customers sometime in a week or so, so we'll see if it becomes available soon.